# Adding a geom_line to histogram for single factor in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Im trying to add a line to the histogram on the level where group == 1

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=age, fill=group)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=10, position="dodge")
```

I tried a lot of different things but I cant seem to make it work.

Maybe it's not geom_line but something else ?

ideally i should have something like [this](https://scontent.fymq3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/279443700_1097861650763638_6819513655064840739_n.png?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=esyafqef7zYAX_QMAzt&_nc_ht=scontent.fymq3-1.fna&oh=03_AVImkb63D4hdWMk1RRgSDcjc9K56EoUR8WqlZxVzkPr8Ew&oe=62938869)

Comment: Could you add the data behind `dat`, using `dput(dat)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to add `density` on your histogram.
Using `diamonds` data as an example,

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=..density..,fill=cut))+
  geom_histogram(position='dodge')+
  geom_density(data=diamonds[diamonds$cut=='Ideal',],alpha=.4)
```

[image]